# How to copy a range on different pages depending on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, copy

For example:

on worksheet1, A1 cell value has data validation for a list, the values of the list are:

-hello
-goodbye

On worksheet2 i have a data range named "hello" and on worksheet3 i have data range named "goodbye"

What i want is that when i choose from the list hello or goodbye the macro copies the range that is named after the value of A1 cell on worksheet1.

Is there a way to do that? i tried making the cell value a string and then use this code: Range("& string &").copy , but the problem is that i dont specify in wich worksheet is the range that i want to copy, so obviously this doesn't work.

help pls

Comment: see [Get sheet name from a named range's Name object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128092/get-sheet-name-from-a-named-ranges-name-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying the `.RefersToRange method, you don't have to go any further with a named range using a Workbook scope.

```
Thisworkbook.names("Hello").referstorange.copy destination:=range("L32")
```

The destination will have to change to suit your own target and *"Hello"* should be a reference to your data validation cell but you should get the idea.